# Multivariable Calc. Integration by Parts

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$$
\iint_S f(\nabla \times \mathbf{A}) \cdot d\mathbf{S} = \oint_{\partial S} f \mathbf{A} \cdot d\mathbf{r} - \iint_S \mathbf{A} \times (\nabla f) \cdot d\mathbf{S}
$$

Is anything wrong with this. My textbook says it should be

$$
\iint_S f(\nabla \times \mathbf{A}) \cdot d\mathbf{S} = \oint_{\partial S} f \mathbf{A} \cdot d\mathbf{r} + \iint_S \mathbf{A} \times (\nabla f) \cdot d\mathbf{S}
$$

Which of the two is correct? I used integration by parts and Stoke's theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Your textbook is correct. It is straighfoward to prove the identity

$$
\vec{\nabla}\times(f\vec{A})=(\vec{\nabla}f)\times\vec{A}+f(\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{A})
$$

Taking a surface integral of both sides, applying Stokes theroem to the left-hand side, and using the antisymmetry of the cross product gets the answer in your textbook.

See also [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities) handy link of vector calculus identities on Wiki.